# Where to Find Data....Project Idea

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data

I am currently taking a SAS class. We were advised to think of a project that we could do on our own, as newbies. Does anyone have any ideas that a newbie to SAS could take on, and where I can find the data for it?

I thought about doing gas prices, and how that relates to holidays; i.e. which specific day would be the best day to buy gas according to trends, as it relates to each holiday--throughout the year; however, the only data I could find was monthly averages and not daily averages. Moreover, it was only for one state, and I would obviously need more data points than just a monthly average for entire states.

Answer (score 2):

The US Energy and Information department keeps a historical weekly dataset on gasoline prices by grade.

https://www.eia.gov/petroleum/gasdiesel/xls/pswrgvwall.xls

Here is another link on their site about getting the data on a per state basis:

http://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.cfm?id=26&t=10